# how to read vars.<varName> in properties component - 'file' field in mule 4

Tags: mule4

My property file name is dev_123.yaml.
dev is an environment variable called env.
123 is a value coming from query param called rollId. Am storing this value in vars.rollId.

In configuration properties component, under 'file' field it will work if I give ${env}_123.yaml.

However, I want to read the value of '123' dynamically via vars too. I tried the following but dint work:

#[p('env') ++ "_" ++ vars.rollId ++ ".yaml"]

${env}_${vars.rollId}.yaml

Answer (score 0):

That will not work. Configuration properties and configuration files are resolved at the startup of a Mule application. Variables are defined during flow execution, after application startup. There is no way to set a variable during start-up. Using configuration properties in the properties file name works because they are resolved at the same time.

An alternative could be to create a custom Mule Module with Mule SDK that implements operations to read properties files dynamically during flow execution. You have to consider if it worth the effort.